# What makes terms of the sum in variance raise to the power of $2$ not $4$ or $6$?

Tags: statistics

If I change the power of the variance to $4$ or $6$, do the properties of the new formula remain the same as the old variance formula? If not what is the difference?

Variance formula:

$$\sigma^2=\frac{\sum(X-\mu)^2}{N}$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Can you list all the property that will be difference as a result in your answer? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @AndréNicolas - By the way, what is "variance of an independent sum is the sum of the variances." that you are talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algebra would become much less nice. We would lose the very useful fact that the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances. With the usual definition of variance, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then 
$$\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y).$$
Sums, and more generally linear combinations of independent random variables are used a great deal in probability theory,

And with the altered definition, variance would become  less useful as a measure of variability. For if we use the power $4$ or $6$, there will be an excessive sensitivity to infrequent large deviations from the mean.

Comment: what is" variance of an independent sum is the sum of the variances.

Comment: Can you show me the property of variance that "variance of an independent sum is the sum of the variances" in formula form please?